# How do you run raw redis commands in PHP?

Tags: php, redis

I have been using predis to try to figure out how to run raw redis commands, but I am having trouble. The documentation for predis is extremely outdated. It says that there is a method called "rawCommand()" which will allow a user to run raw Redis commands, but I found a changelog that says it is no longer supported:
https://github.com/nrk/predis/blame/master/CHANGELOG

Does anyone have any hints of how I can run raw redis commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. This has worked perfectly for me, and I did not know it even had that function

```
$cmdSet = $redis->createCommand('set');
$cmdSet->setArgumentsArray(array('library', 'predis'));
$cmdSetReply = $redis->executeCommand($cmdSet);
```

He has a [wiki page](https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Quick-tour) on this. Look for sending commands.

Comment: This works only on "known" commands. See my answer how to add new commands

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually guessing here, but let's pretend for a while I did not say that aloud.

Check out the function writeCommand() in lib/Predis/Network/StreamConnection.php on line 176 and use it through SimpleDebuggableConnection in examples/SimpleDebuggableConnection.php. You still have to define new commands that are not already defined in lib/predis/commands, as mentioned in the wiki that @Colum referred to.

If you're really feeling adventurous, change the protected method writeBytes() in StreamConnection on line 96 to public. That should enable you to feed it pure redis with

```
$redis->getConnection()->writeBytes("*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$5\r\nmykey\r\n$7\r\nmyvalue\r\n")
```

Unfortunately, publicizing the writeBytes() seems to go in to the direction of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_orgy anti-pattern.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy!
Take this class: [RedisServer](https://github.com/jamm/Memory/blob/master/RedisServer.php)
and write:

```
$redis = new \Jamm\Memory\RedisServer();
$redis->send_command('set','key',5); //here any raw command
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHPRedis

on `phpredis` extension you can use following:

```
$redis->rawCommand("count", "a:", 10, "a:");
```

## PRedis

on `phpredis` you can use following:

```
$redis->executeRaw(["count", "a:", 10, "a:"]);
```

## PRedis - more complicated way

on `predis` you can do like this:

```
<?php
require 'Predis/Autoloader.php';
Predis\Autoloader::register();

class PRredisCOUNT extends Predis\Command\Command {
    function getId(){
        return 'COUNT';
    }
}

class PRredisSUM extends Predis\Command\Command {
    function getId(){
        return 'SUM';
    }
}

function registerHM4Commands($redis){
    $redis->getProfile()->defineCommand("count" , "PRredisCOUNT"    );
    $redis->getProfile()->defineCommand("sum"       , "PRredisSUM"      );
}

$redis = new Predis\Client("127.0.0.1:2000");

registerHM4Commands($redis);

// after that you can do:

$redis->count($key, $page, $prefix);
```